# How Do I Fire A Tracking Pixel With A PHP Script From The Shell Without Anyone Being On The Site?

Tags: php, pixel

How Do I Fire A Tracking Pixel With A PHP Script From The Shell Without Anyone Being On The Site?

I have tried hitting a script with just the pixel in it with wget, and lynx but I cannot get the pixel to fire because for it to fire it "has" to be displayed in the browser.

It's just a standard image pixel, or iframe pixel given to me by a affiliate network.

I know other affiliate networks have this capability, to fire a pixel without a person being on the website - but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Any suggestions?

---

**From the comments**
Sorry guys, trying not to be shady. In the payday loan space, there are many networks that use a pingtree, and fire the pixel only when a certain sales amount threshold is hit. This is above board, no trickery involved. it's called the bucket method. A virtual bucket is put in place, and money gets thrown in it, when it reaches a certain dollar amount the pixel is fired and the bucket resets to 0.00

Comment: So, the idea is to trick the affiliate and think they are getting the pixel displayed?

Comment: Get the exact url requested by the browser when it fetches the web bug and use wget on that. You may also have to tell wget to supply a referer and/or browser ID string to get the 'hit' registered properly. The tracking co has to have some kind of basic validation on the hits, otherwise what you're doing would be a trivial method to boost traffic counts into orbit. Which, of course, could be exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @OhCaN If it would only be so easy. Those affiliates are not stupid. :)

Comment: Downvoting because this seems really shady. Feel free to prove me wrong, though.

Comment: Sorry guys, trying not to be shady.  In the payday loan space, there are many networks that use a pingtree, and fire the pixel only when a certain sales amount threshold is hit.  This is above board, no trickery involved.  it's called the bucket method.  A virtual bucket is put in place, and money gets thrown in it, when it reaches a certain dollar amount the pixel is fired and the bucket resets to 0.00

Comment: Fair enough. If you edit your post with that information, I'll reverse my vote (it's locked in right now). Cheers!

Comment: What does "fire a tracking pixel" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The browser loads the HTML, parses it and then loads all images. You just get the HTML and nothing else. You should get the pixel too.

But If this is too fool someone, most trackers will keep track of IP addresses, so all your views will probably count as 0 or as 1, or you'll get real trouble with your affiliate.

Answer (score 0):

> because for it to fire it "has" to be displayed in the browser.

Fetching the image with `wget` will work.

Whether it gets displayed in the browser or not does not matter for an image resource.

Maybe the site serving the pixel has means in place to prevent automatic fetching.

Comment: I believe you are correct, but it sure won't fire!  I can have a script that has echo "-the image code-"; alone in the script and hit it with wget and it will not fire.  Of course its a img src = http://www.whatever.com/pixelfirescript.php?aid=977&subid=j8 - sorry I cant put real code in, it tries to shows up as a image.

Comment: @user that won't work of course. Do a direct request *to the image*. If you can't do that, try `wget --page-requisites`

Comment: Some of the pixels are Javascript, and some are Iframes so they can't be direct requested :(  I know there's a way, it's just elusive.

Comment: @user then you'll have to start parsing the JavaScript and iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for certain, but the problem might be the `User-Agent`.  The affiliate probably only fires it when the `User-Agent` is a legitimate browser.  Wget probably has its own `User-Agent` string.  Try hooking up Fiddler or WireShark when you make a real request in the browser.  Then you should be able to replay the HTTP request manually via php (or any language).

Comment: Trusting that you'll only use this for ethical purposes.

Comment: Hey there.  I'm actually doing testing using a little pixel system I setup which has no restrictions on it.  So anyone with any user agent can fire it.  Problem is, for it to fire it supposedly has to be displayed in a browser.. but wget don't do that nor lynx.

Comment: I'm not sure what a web-browser does differently in loading an image other than just requesting the URL.  Have you tried mimicking the request exactly using something like WireShark, Fiddler, or netcat?

Answer (score 0):

it was as simple as

wget -r url

I haven't tested on iframe though, but it did work for image pixels.